# undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) when no array is empty while using reject

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby 1.9. I have the following:

```
add1 = [record['a'], record['b'], record['c']]
full_add = add1.reject!(&:empty?).join(", ")

# scenario 1
record['a'] = 'Good'
record['b'] = ''
record['c'] = 'Fine'
# >> Good, Fine

# scenario 2
record['a'] = 'Good'
record['b'] = 'Boy'
record['c'] = 'Fine'
# >> undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

When I inspect the `full_add` for scenario 2, it returns error, because no array is empty. How should I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `reject!` returns `nil` if nothing was rejected, use `reject` (without `!`) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You canno't do it in one line :

```
add1 = [record['a'], record['b'], record['c']]
add1.reject!(&:empty?) if add1.include? ""
full_add = add1.join(", ")
```

be carefull with method suffixed by !, this kind of method alterate the object himself, and do not work with their returned value